# Field of definition of compatible system of Galois representations

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

Let $K,F$ be number fields and suppose that there is a compatible system of Galois representations
$$(\rho_{\lambda} : \text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K) \longrightarrow \text{GL}_n(\overline{F}_\lambda) )$$
such that the field generated by the traces of Frobenius is $F$.

Define the set
$$S=\{ \ \lambda \ | \ \rho_\lambda \ \text{cannot be conjugated into} \ \text{GL}_n(F_\lambda) \ \}.$$

What can we say about the set $S$ in general? For example is it always finite? Is it possible to say more in specific instances, for example $n=2$ and $K$ totally real?